# Listening to incoming SMS after broadcast is unregistered: nice feature or broadcastreciever's bug?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have an application which should watching incoming SMS (scan SMS text and show toast messages based on content) , even after my application is closed. The desired functionality is app watching all incoming SMS until app will not moved from device, and now it works like this. But I think, if I will need soon, to "switch of" this "watching eye", how I could to do this?

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {
       //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

        if (bundle != null)
        {
          //do some action
        }
  }
```

BroadcastReceiver's code is a separate unit SMSReceiver.java. From main Activity I do not call this receiver, do not register and do not unregister. It's just working independently. Amazing. 
So.. how I can ti stop this receiver??

Comment: Do you mean that the Receiver is in the Manifest with an SMS Receive Intent Filter?

Comment: Yes, receiver is decribed in Manifest: <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
  <intent-filter> 
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>

Comment: When the receiver is in the manifest the reciever is "always on".

Comment: Ah... thank so much, Dan! Probably this is true for all Manifest properties.

Comment: In this case (for "always on") I have no way to close it? right? only if I'll register and unregister receiver in program code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to take the `BroadcastReceiver` out of your Manifest to control it such as using it in a `Service` or `Activity`. When its in the Manifest its always on.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to register/unregister `BroadcastReceivers` is to use the `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods of your `Activity`.

Firstly remove the `<intent-filter>` from your manifest, i.e., delete this section......

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECIEVED"></action>
</intent-filter>
```

Then add something like this to your `Activity`....

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private final String ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private SMSReceiver smsReceiver = null;
    private Boolean isReceiverRegistered = false;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (!isReceiverRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED));
            isReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (isReceiverRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
            isReceiverRegistered = false;
        }
    }
}
```